# cakephp3 test component Call to a member function on() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp, testing, tdd, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to test my plugin component written for cakephp 3.

This is my component:

```
namespace CurrencyConverter\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class CurrencyConverterComponent extends Component
{
    public $controller = null;

    public function setController($controller)
    {
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }

    public function startup($event)
    {
        $this->setController($event->subject());
    }


    public function convert($fromCurrency, $toCurrency, $amount, $saveIntoDb = 1, $hourDifference = 1, $dataSource = 'default') {

    }
}
```

and this is mt test:

```
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Controller\Component;

use CurrencyConverter\Controller\Component\CurrencyConverterComponent;
use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry;
use Cake\Network\Request;
use Cake\Network\Response;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;

class CurrencyConverterComponentTest extends TestCase {
    public $fixtures = ['app.currencyconverter'];
    public $CurrencyConverter = null;
    public $controller = null;

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        // Setup our component and fake test controller
        $request = new Request();
        $response = new Response();
        $this->controller = $this->getMock(
            'Cake\Controller\Controller',
            [],
            [$request, $response]
        );
        $registry = new ComponentRegistry($this->controller);
        $this->CurrencyConverter = new CurrencyConverterComponent($registry);
    }

    public function testAmountWithComma() {
        $fromCurrency   = 'EUR';
        $toCurrency     = 'GBP';
        $amount         = '20,00';
        $saveIntoDb     = 0;
        $hourDifference = 0;
        $dataSource     = 'test';

        $result = $this->CurrencyConverter->convert($fromCurrency, $toCurrency, $amount, $saveIntoDb, $hourDifference, $dataSource);

        $this->assertGreaterThan($result, $amount);
    }
}
```

When I run tests I get this error in the core!!

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function on() on a non-object in /Users/alessandrominoccheri/Sites/cakephp3/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php on line 289
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to test here? The component or the controller?

Comment: The component in this test @JoséLorenzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  this particular case you are mocking too much. You are telling phpunit to mock *all* methods in the controller, including the `eventManager()` getter method, which makes the controller try to call `on()` on a null object.

You need to only mock the methods you are interested in testing, that will alter the environment, or try to communicate with external services. Also, it seems like you are trying to test the Component instead of the Controller, the purpose of the test is not very clear.

To me, it seems like your CurrencyConverter class should not be a component, but just a class in your project that you could use anywhere. There is no need to attach such a class to controllers.

Comment: Ok but in this case I need to use it as a Component because I have omitted the rest of code. Could you please let me know how to fix the problem of mock? Thanks

Comment: `$component = new CurrencyConverter(new ComponentRegistry(new Controller))`